# Phone Call Events - JQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm new to mobile development, I want to make an app which calls a phone number without opening up the phone dialer screen instead to make the call in background from my app page as the user browses. Is it possible to have events to make a call/end call using Jquery Mobile? I currently see some option in Phonegap using events but wondering its possible in Jquery Mobile? or HTML5 API?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you could add `tel:` before the number in `href` of anchor, like this:

```
<a class="phone branch-a" href="tel:(22) 2222-222" title="Branch A">Branch A</a>
```

About you being able to call from your app, you'll have to build a phonedialer yourself. Its always good to fallback on android systems whenever possible.

Comment: I would add that this has nothing to do with jqm and that the "tel" protocol might not be implemented in older android versions

Comment: so I have to build an hybrid app? it can't be done fully in HTML5/JS app?